# How to remove this ever occuring Warning, which appears every time I open a terminal?

Tags: linux

How to remove this ever occuring Warning, which appears every time I open a terminal?

```
 * Warning: removing empty lock file
 * Error: failed to remove empty lock file
 * Error: failed to get the lock: /usr/bin/keychain: 1492: cannot create /home/prashant/.keychain/http://prashant-laptop.promptcloud.com/-lockf: Directory nonexistent
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're running keychain on a SSH key in one of your login rc files (like `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`). It's trying to import a key named "http://prashant-laptop.promptcloud.com/" and create a lock file with that name, but slashes in the name make it address a directory that doesn't exist.

I suggest changing the label, removing the keychain line entirely, or adding `--nolock` to your keychain login line (which is probably something like `/usr/bin/keychain "$HOME/.ssh/id_dsa`)